# Expand table and duplicate rows based on lookup with multiple levels

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset and lookup in this format:

```
library(dplyr)

Data <- tibble(
           Code = c("A001", "A002", "A003","B001","B002", "C001","D044"),
           CodeLevel = c("Level1", "Level1", "Level1","Level2","Level2", "Level3","Level4"),
           Value1 = 1:7,
           Value2 = 101:107,
           Value3 = 201:207)
           
Lookup <- tibble(
            Level1 = paste0("A",sprintf("%03d", 1:15)),
            Level2 = c(rep("B010",3),rep("B009",2), "B002",rep("B001",2),"B002",rep("B007",4),rep("B008",2)),
            Level3 = c(rep("C006",3),rep("C001",3),rep("C006",2),rep("C001",2), rep("C003",3),rep("C004",2)),
            Level4 = c(rep("D023",5) , rep("D044",10)))
```

I want to report the data in my `Data` table at the `Level1` level using the lookup table. So anything that isn't Level1, those rows are repeated, but with a unique `Level1` identifier added and the values in `Value1` to `Value3` repeated.

The output I am after would look like this:

```
Output <- tibble(
            ID = c(paste0("A",sprintf("%03d", 1:3)),rep("A007",2), "A006", "A009", paste0("A",sprintf("%03d", 4:6)),"A009","A010",paste0("A",sprintf("%03d", 6:15))),
            Code = c(paste0("A",sprintf("%03d", 1:3)),rep("B001",2),rep("B002",2), rep("C001",5),rep("D044",10)),
            CodeLevel = c(rep("Level1",3),rep("Level2",4), rep("Level3",5),rep("Level4",10)),
            Value1 = c(1:3,rep(4,2),rep(5,2),rep(6,5),rep(7,10)),   
            Value2 = c(101:103,rep(104,2),rep(105,2),rep(106,5),rep(107,10)),       
            Value3 = c(201:203,rep(204,2),rep(205,2),rep(206,5),rep(207,10)))           
            
Output %>% print(n=nrow(Output))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
Lookup1=  Lookup %>% pivot_longer(cols= Level2:Level4,names_to = "Levels",values_to = "Code")
Lookuplong= Lookup %>% pivot_longer(cols= Level1:Level4,names_to = "CodeLevel",values_to = "Code")

Lookupmerged = merge(Lookuplong,Lookup1[,c(1,3)],by="Code",all.x = TRUE)%>% distinct() %>% 
                mutate(ID= ifelse(is.na(Level1),Code,Level1)) %>% select(-Level1)

                  
Output = merge(Data,Lookupmerged,by =c("CodeLevel","Code"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Triparna Poddar's answer and in case anyone wants a version without all of `tidyverse` loaded. This is using `dplyr 1.1.1` and `tidyr 1.3.0`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Lookup1 <- Lookup %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols= Level2:Level4, names_to = "Levels", values_to = "Code")
Lookuplong <- Lookup %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols= Level1:Level4, names_to = "CodeLevel", values_to = "Code")

Lookupmerged <- Lookuplong %>%
    left_join(., Lookup1 %>% select(Level1,Code),join_by(Code == Code),relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
    distinct() %>% 
    mutate(ID = ifelse(is.na(Level1),Code,Level1)) %>% 
    select(-Level1)

Output <- Data %>%
    left_join(., Lookupmerged, join_by(CodeLevel, Code)) %>%
    relocate(ID, .before = Code)
```